# Can't run uvicorn --version

Tags: web-services, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm trying [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/) but I can't even run the Hello World example.
I've installed both `uvicorn` and `fastapi` with a venv and `requirements.txt`, also I'm running Python 3.5 (maybe that's the issue?)

The issue should be something with uvicorn because I can't run `--help` or `--version`

```
uvicorn --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/...../.venv/bin/uvicorn", line 7, in <module>
    from uvicorn.main import main
  File "/home/...../.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/uvicorn/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from uvicorn.config import Config
  File "/home/...../.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 131
    message = f"Uvicorn running on {ip_repr} (Press CTRL+C to quit)"
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I really don't have a clue where to start looking as I cannot seem to find anything on internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely with Python 3.5, FastAPI won't work.

FastAPI homepage:

> FastAPI is a modern, fast (high-performance), web framework for building APIs with Python 3.6+ based on standard Python type hints.

uvicorn (from https://github.com/encode/uvicorn):

> Requirements: Python 3.6+ (For Python 3.5 support, install version 0.8.6.)

I guess you should update Python to 3.6 at least. [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) should help.

Comment: Excellent! For the record, it worked with pyenv and Python 3.6.8 but it didn't work for 3.6.0

Comment: weird because the docs states clearly 3.6+. I didn't test with 3.6.x, I can say that with 3.7.3 (Debian) everything works fine